# How to keep the code dry while using a function in selenium with testng?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, testng

Let's assume that I have a method that when called makes a screenshot of the page and saves it in a folder. I want to know a better way of using the method without repeating myself because right now is working like this (I am using selenium-webdriver with testng and java):

```
public class TestClass{

@Test
public void firstTest(){
  step1();
  step2();
  takeScreenshot();
  step3();
  takeScreenshot();
  step4();
  takeScreenshot();
  step5();
  step6();
  takeScreenshot();
}

@Test
public void secondTest(){
  step1();
  step2();
  takeScreenshot();
  step3();
  takeScreenshot();
  step4();
  step5();
  step6();
  takeScreenshot();
}


}
```

As you can see, right now I call the method after any step in the test methods when I need to capture a screenshot but it doesn't look too clean. So I am wondering if it is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are the steps do. But if those are the assertions then you could just split them in separate tests and call the screenshot method in the `@AfterTest` method. That way after every test screenshot will be taken and you don't have to repeat the screenshot method call.

Comment: The "steps*();"  can be anything (assertions, logs, selenium api calls. etc). Now, regarding your purposed solution, If I do it like that, the number of test cases will be increased because I will split them just to use the @AfterTest annotation.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that what you have right now is not too bad.  It's simple, explicit, and easily configurable (i.e. `step4()` has a screenshot in the first test, but not the second).  You want to abstract away the screenshots because they feel like clutter, but you're making a decision as the author to call it in some situations and not others, and that decision has to be encoded somewhere.

That said, you could...

A) Bury `takeScreenshot()` down in the `step()` functions, and pass in a flag that triggers it when true.  However, using flags like this violates the [Do One Thing](https://www.investigatii.md/uploads/resurse/Clean_Code.pdf#page=66) principle, which makes Uncle Bob grumpy.

```
public void secondTest(){
  step1();
  step2(true);
  step3(true);
  step4();
  step5();
  step6(true);
}
```

B) You could do something REALLY fancy and make all of your `step()` functions return `this`, so you can chain them with `takeScreenshot()` (which I assume is elsewhere in `TestClass`).  That would allow you to commit this (probably terrible) crime:

```
public void secondTest(){
  step1();
  step2().takeScreenshot();
  step3().takeScreenshot();
  step4();
  step5();
  step6().takeScreenshot();
}
```

C) Sacrifice the ability to configure whether or not the screenshot is taken after a given action, and just hardcode it into the set of actions you care most about.

D) Or my favorite option, leave it as is.  Just because you're calling a function over and over doesn't mean your code isn't DRY.  You're not duplicating any real logic.  It's more lines of code, but hey, you're not going to run out of lines.  Ditching cruft and syntax can make your code more readable, but if you squeeze it too much, trying to do 20 things in 12 lines, it can backfire.  Treat yourself to those extra lines of code, it's the weekend, you deserve it.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to go like this: make each "step" method into a test. Then, use TestNG annotations of @BeforeTest or @AfterTest like this:

```
@Test
public void Step1()
{
    // write here step1 code...
}

@Test
public void Step2()
{
    // write here step2 code...
}

@AfterTest
public void takeScreenshot()
{
    // takeScreenshot method code goes here
}
```

This way the takeScreenshot method will run after each step and you will get a cleaner a better code.